# how to implement getOrCreateNodeWithUniqueFactory method right

Tags: neo4j

OK,
I built the whole program in http://architects.dzone.com/articles/and-now-something-completely
and everything works fine except the function: `getOrCreateNodeWithUniqueFactory()`

(
its mean when I make a new node without checking whether it already exists then it works but it's not my goal my goal is when the entity exists not to create a new Node.
)

so i checked here http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-unique-nodes.html#tutorials-java-embedded-unique-get-or-create-with-factory

now i have three options but I like the option of first or second (Cypher and unique constraints or UniqueFactory )

I can not figure out whether all lines of code each example should be in the same scope (same function) or in two separate functions 
and If necessary in two separate functions, when I call each of them?

Answer (score 2):

If you can go with unique constraints and cypher `MERGE` that should be good enough.

Otherwise, what I usually do is to create a class for my unique node factory

```
class UserUniqueFactory extends UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory {
    public PersonUniqueFactory(GraphDatabaseService graphDb) { 
       super( graphDb, "users" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void initialize( Node created, Map<String, Object> properties )
    {
        created.addLabel( DynamicLabel.label( "User" ) );
        created.setProperty( "name", properties.get( "name" ) );
    }
    public Node create(String username) {
       return getOrCreate("name",username);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
factory = new UserUniqueNodeFactory(graphDb);
try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
{
    Node node = factory.create(username);
    tx.success();
    return node;
}
```